# (C) Let $R$ be the square of length 0.02 centred at $(1,1)$. Find the area of $f(R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Suppose that $f$: ℝ$^2$ $\rightarrow$ ℝ$^2$ is a differentiable function. The best linear approximation of f near (a,b) is the affine function

$T(x,y)$ = $Df(a,b)(x-a, y-b) + f(a,b)$

where $Df(a,b)$ is the 2x2 Jacobian matrix for $f$ at $(a,b)$.

(A) What should we expect the ratio of the area of f(S) to the area of S to be for small objects centred at (a,b)?

My answer: Since $S$ is a small object centred at $(a,b)$, and $f$ is best approximated by $T$, $T(S)$ is the best approximation for $f(s)$. Therefore, the area of $f(s)$ is best approximated by the area of $T(S)$ = $|det(Df(a,b))|$.

(B) Suppose that $f(x,y)$ = $(x^2, y^2)$. Find the Jacobian of $f$ at $(1,1)$.

My answer: $f(x,y)$ = $(x^2, y^2)$. $f_x(x,y)$ = $(2x,0)$, $f_y(x,y) = (0,2y)$. Therefore, $Df(x,y)$ = \begin{matrix}
        \ 2x & 0 \\
        0 & \ 2y \\
        \end{matrix}

$\implies$ $Df(1,1)$ = \begin{matrix}
        \ 2 & 0 \\
        0 & \ 2 \\
        \end{matrix}

Therefore, Jacobian = 4.

(C) Let $R$ be the square of length 0.02 centred at (1,1). Find the area of F(R) to confirm your answer in part (A).

I'm not sure how to solve this (C). If someone could please post a solution, as well as their reasoning behind why you did each step, I would appreciate it. Note that I really do need a good explanation to gain a conceptual understanding of what is going on (learning), rather than just a solution alone. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The corners of the small square are $(0.99,0.99)$, $(1.01,1.01)$ and two others.  Compute the area of the small square, then find $f($each corner$)$ and find the area of the figure formed by those four points.  You should find that each side of the image square is about twice as long as the starting square, leading to an area four times as large.  This matches your Jacobian.

Comment: In this case, _exactly_ twice as long.

Comment: But what is the reasoning behind this solution? My goal is to learn, which requires conceptual understanding.

Comment: The Jacobian is the local change in area.  We are just validating that the behavior is as expected in this case.  The exercise is supposed to help your understanding of the fact.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't do anything to help someone learn. Why do I find f(each corner)? What is the significance of this?

Comment: You are trying to find (an approximation) to the shape the small square is sent to by $f$.  Finding where the corners go is a good way to do that.  As long as the shape is small, it will be a good approximation to join the images of the corners by straight lines in the image space.  This makes it easy to see how the area changes.

Comment: @RossMillikan Interesting. And how does the equation for the tangent plane factor into this? In this case, we are just taking f(vertices), but we're not using the equation of the tangent plane shown above?

Comment: You can compare the vertices you get with the expression from the tangent plane.  You will find they differ by $0.0001$, which is the square of $\Delta x$ (or $y$).  This is why it is only accurate for small areas.